# How does the placement of transition sentences affects the meaning/tone of a piece?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, editing, pacing

Example:

> Finally, I began questioning the kid. What was her name? Where were
>   her parents? And most important, what was she doing outside in this
>   horrible weather? She replied to none of that. In fact, she didn’t
>   utter a single word; all she did was to stare at me with her uncanny
>   eyes. **Luckily, I obtained that information by other means.**
>
> That night, after the kid had gone to sleep, I found a letter in her
>   backpack.
>
> ---
>
> Finally, I began questioning the kid. What was her name? Where were
>   her parents? And most important, what was she doing outside in this
>   horrible weather? She replied to none of that. In fact, she didn’t
>   utter a single word; all she did was to stare at me with her uncanny
>   eyes.
>
> **Luckily, I obtained that information by other means.**
>
> That night, after the kid had gone to sleep, I found a letter in her
>   backpack.
>
> ---
>
> Finally, I began questioning the kid. What was her name? Where were
>   her parents? And most important, what was she doing outside in this
>   horrible weather? She replied to none of that. In fact, she didn’t
>   utter a single word; all she did was to stare at me with her uncanny
>   eyes.
>
> **Luckily, I obtained that information by other means.** That night, after the kid had gone to sleep, I found a letter in her
>   backpack.

How does the meaning/tone differ in passages above?

Comment: Reading this except on its own, I think the bolded sentence can be struck out entirely. Unless the text that precedes the except ties in with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence implies that action took place which the reader is not seeing (the "other means"). Wherever that sentence is, that's where/when you're placing this off-screen action.

However, because the action of finding the letter physically happens in the next paragraph (that is, it's *not* off-screen), it has to be the idea or the decision to search her backpack which is the Other Means in that sentence.

- In the first example, the Other Means sounds like an idea which
  occurs to the narrator while s/he's questioning the girl.
- In the second example, the Other Means is being presented as a
  narrative device: this is the narrator explaining something to the
  reader as though we were in the room with him/her, having an actual
  conversation about these events.
- In the third example, it sounds like the narrator only came up with
  the idea to search the girl's backpack after she'd fallen asleep.

Which one works better is simply a matter of when you want the idea to occur to the narrator.

Answer (score 0):

As far as tone goes, I think the first and third are equivalent.  In the 2nd case, putting the sentence in a paragraph of its own adds emphasis to the statement.  Also in this particular case the statement is vague which hints to the reader that the details are forthcoming which is a trick often used to build suspense.